# Issiues retrieving data with HTTP and show in view with ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to get my JSON data to show in a app using ionic.

Im getting the following error when trying to output the data:

*ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.*

**My data looks like this:**

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "John",
    "lastname": "Jonson",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
  "5": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Parker",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
  "8": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Lo",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
}
```

**My HTML code:**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ion-item>{{ user.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**And finaly the js code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    users: Observable<any>;

    usersList = [];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient) {

        this.users = this.httpClient.get('http://example.com/api/user');

        this.users.subscribe(data => {
            this.usersList = data,
             console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON structure is not a JSON array, that's why you can't iterate it

Comment: so i cant use the api or do i need to convert it to json?

Comment: you can convert your JSON into an array, first is you need create an object that will handle the array of objects. Then you need to return all the keys from the root object (original JSON). Then get the value (as object) per key. Then push each object value (together with the key ID) to the object you created

Comment: i re-did the API so it looks like the example below, but im still getting the same error.

Comment: update your post then, what are the changes you made in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data as an object array with keys.

```
Object.keys(yourData).forEach(value=>{ this.users.push({Key: value, User: data[value]})})
```

and template like below:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let user of users">
   <ion-item>{{ user.User.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

So let your data needs to look like this.

```
const myData = [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "lastname": "Jonson",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Parker",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Lo",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "image": ""
  },
]
```

More on arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array